# alsamixer crashes with my asound.conf file, but is fine without it

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, alsa, mpd

I'm having a peculiar problem with alsamixer.  I have this asound.conf file that performs a channel remapping for my "USBStreamer" device:

```
pcm.usbSTR {
  type hw
  card USBStreamer
  device 0
}

pcm.usbREMAP {
  type plug
  slave.pcm usbSTR
  ttable.0.8 1
  ttable.1.9 1
}

pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave.pcm usbREMAP
}

ctl.!default {
  type plug
  slave.pcm usbREMAP
}
```

If I run alsamixer with no command-line arguments and the above asound.conf file, alsamixer crashes with the not-so-helpful error message:

```
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:254:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_plug.so
cannot open mixer: No such device or address
```

If I delete the asound.conf file, alsamixer works perfectly.

Unfortunately, I need the channel remapping for mpd to work.

Is there a way to have channel remapping and not have alsamixer crash?

FYI: if I specify the USBStreamer device, alsamixer runs fine.  Unfortunately it appears mpd is not so specific when it calls alsamixer.

edit: If I erase the ctl.!default block from asound.conf, and restart alsa, alsamixer runs fine without specifying a device. . . mpd *thinks* its playing through alsa, but no noise comes out of my speakers.  I think that ctl.!default block was doing something important.

Also, speaker-test is no longer working. It's complaining about a busy resource:

```
speaker-test -c 10 -t sin -D plughw:USBStreamer

speaker-test 1.1.0

Playback device is plughw:USBStreamer
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 10 channels
Sine wave rate is 440.0000Hz
Playback open error: -16,Device or resource busy
```

Here is my audio_output part of /etc/mpd.conf

```
audio_output {
type "alsa"
name "USB Streamer - LX521.4"
device "hw:USBStreamer,0"
}
```

Although this is peripheral to my problem, I found that asound.conf file a little ugly.   My understanding of ALSA configuration files is rudimentary but I believe this is equivalent to the above (with the ctl.!default part erased):

```
pcm.!default {
  type plug
  slave.pcm {
    type hw
    card USBStreamer
    device 0
    }
   ttable {
    0.8 1
    1.9 1
  }
}
```

Here is the amixer "simple controls" for the sound device:

```
amixer -D hw:USBStreamer scontrols
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
Simple mixer control 'Mic',1
Simple mixer control 'USBStreamer Clock Selector',0
Simple mixer control 'USBStreamer Output',0
Simple mixer control 'USBStreamer Output',1
```

Aha!  It looks like perhaps mpd is using ALSA and that's why I can't do the speaker-test:

```
 sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*
[sudo] password for rybu: 
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/snd/controlC0:  mpd         935 F.... mpd
/dev/snd/pcmC1D0p:   mpd         935 F...m mpd
```

It does seem like mpd is frozen.  Requests to mpc take forever and result in error messages like:

```
mpc
mpd error: Timeout
```

So I need to kill mpd for a bit. . . let's see if I can do that.  I believe a "sudo service mpd stop" should do the trick.  That request is taking a long time. . . okay, speaker-test is working again!

but mplayer is not working:

```
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pcm.c:2135:(snd_pcm_open_conf) type is not defined
[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: No such file or directory
Failed to initialize audio driver 'alsa'
[AO SDL] Samplerate: 44100Hz Channels: Stereo Format s16le
[AO SDL] using aalib audio driver.
[AO SDL] Unable to open audio: 
Failed to initialize audio driver 'sdl:aalib'
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
Audio: no sound
```

Okay, I fixed that with the mplayer arguments "ao=alsa:device=default" this tells it to use the asound.conf remapped default device.

Next, mpd.  It feels good to be making progress.

I set mpd to use the default ALSA device (not hw:USBStreamer) so that the channel remapping is done.  Restart mpd, and it works perfectly again.

Thanks, problem solved.

Comment: There is no `plug` plugin for a `ctl` device. The only possible type is `hw`, and the only option is `card`.

Comment: @CL. thanks.  Okay, so somehow my broken asound.conf file used to work, with previous versions of ALSA and MPD.  Now it does not.  Do you know any good resources that would give me enough information to correct my asound.conf file?  When I first built that file I had some guidance from an ALSA developer. Now, I do not.  On top of that, I've forgotten much of the basics.

Comment: You do not need the `ctl` definition (you can configure the mixer in mpd, if needed.)

Comment: @CL. Thanks.  Okay I'll try that.  Unfortunately I can't get speaker-test to work anymore, it complains about a busy resource.   So there appears to be a more basic problem.  Do you know how to check to see what is occupying ALSA?

Comment: How did you configure the mixer in mpd?

Comment: @CL. I've edited-in my audio_output portion from mpd.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about that `ctl` device; to configure the mpd mixer, set its [mixer_type](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/config_audio_outputs.html) and/or [mixer_device](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/output_plugins.html#alsa_output). (If the device does not have a usable mixer controls, you might need to use the software mixer.)

The busy error is caused by some other program (probably) PulseAudio opening the device.
(You can check the PID in `/proc/asound/cardX/pcm0p/sub0/status`.)

Comment: I've removed the ctl device and edited my question.  It does not appear that pulse is using the device -- pulse isn't an active process.  Do you know how to check what ALSA thinks it is doing?  I recall there is a file somewhere where alsa lists its current state, but /var/lib/alsa/asound.state does not appear to be it.   Thanks for the advice on the mpd mixer_device -- I will try that once I can get ALSA working again.

Comment: It wasn't pulseaudio, it was mpd that was using ALSA.  I put the details in the revised question.  speaker-test is working now, but mplayer is not.  I'll see if I can get mplayer working before I try your mixer suggestions in mpd.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  My problem is solved.  After pointing mpd to use the default alsa device, it works again.  I did not need to set the mixer device -- alsa (or mpd) seems to have figured that out.  But I might want to look into this later to see what it's doing.